# Connection intermittently refused only when using Apache commons FTPClient

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I am attempting to use `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` to connect to a server and download some files.  When I run the code on my Windows 7 machine it consistently connects and downloads the files.  When I run it on an AIX box it fails 80% of the time, throwing a `java.net.ConnectException`, with a message of *"A remote host refused an attempted connect operation"*. It eventually connects if I retry often enough. If I log onto the AIX box where the `FTPClient` code is unable to connect consistently, and use ftp from the command line to connect to the same server that the code is having trouble connecting to, it consistently connects and I can download the file. Once `FTPClient` connects I don't have any problems. It's just the connection that's causing me problems.  Any idea's why `FTPClient` would be having problems on AIX? Again, it's not that it never connects, just that it does so inconsistently.  Below is the code that I'm using to connect.

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();

try{
    ftp.connect(server);
    reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
}catch(Exception e){
    log.error("FTPClient failed to connect: " + e.getClass().getName() + " " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

Below is the stacktrace from the exception.

```
java.net.ConnectException: A remote host refused an attempted connect operation.
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:370)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:232)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:219)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:168)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:189)
at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:278)
at com.nbi.plex.Builder.downLoad(Builder.java:198)
```

Comment: try seting setConnectTimeout on your client and make sure FTP server is running and port is open . Looks like FTP server is busy and FTPClient not able to wait enough to get the connection.

Comment: The stacktrace you posted is either incomplete or from a different section of your code.  `FTPClient` should show up somewhere in the stack trace.

Comment: I increased the connection timeout to 10 seconds and I still can't connect.

Comment: Jim Garrison, that stacktrace is definitely from the exception.  I agree that FTPClient should be in there.  I have no explanation why it's not.  I'm not attempting a connection with anything other than FTPClient.  Line 198 in my code is where the call to FTPClient.connect is made.